Laravel 11 migrations for foreign keys in different tables
I've tried to solve this for two days and am finally throwing in the towel to ask for help.
I am trying to get a database setup with a number of tables, relevant here is:
Table: Collections:
Schema::create('collections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('owner_id')->constrained(table:'users', indexName: 'collections_users_id');
            $table->foreignId('library_id')->nullable()->constrained(table:'libraries', indexName: 'collections_libraries_id');
            [...]
            $table->timestamps();
        });

And as you'll see above, I try to set up a nullable foreign key to the libraries table. That table is defined in its separate migrations doc as follows:
Schema::create('libraries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('creator_id')->constrained(table: 'users', indexName: 'collections_users_id');
            [...]            $table->timestamps();
        });

The owner_id foreign key works without issue. I then get the following error when I run the migration:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `TABLENAME`.`collections` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `collections` add constraint `collections_library_id_foreign` foreign key (`library_id`) references `libraries` (`id`))

Migrations doesn't run the libraries file until after collections, which I assume is the core issue. But I can't figure out how I am supposed to work around it. What am I missing?
